# JTextArea keeps scrolling the main panel to the top

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have defined a JTextArea as follows:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setText("Some text");
textArea.setEditable(true);
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setAutoscrolls(false);
```

Now this component is one of a number of components which has been added to the main JPanel which is defined as follows:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setName("Some name");

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setName("Some name");
scrollPane.getViewport().add(panel);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setAutoscrolls(false);
```

Now the JTextArea component appears near the bottom of the main panel and is partly hidden so you have to scroll down in order to see it all. But the problem I'm getting is that when I click on it, the main panel automatically scrolls back to the top again, hiding most of my JTextArea component again. So after clicking on it, the user has to then scroll down again in order to type something in.

But I can't work out why it's doing this. Is there a problem with using a JTextArea? If I use a JTextField then the problem doesn't occur.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: hard to tell without SSCCE, but might be similar to [a recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14277765/203657) BTW: scrollbar policies and autoscrolls are unrelated to scrolling behaviour

Comment: can you provide a sample working code demonstrating that issue? to provide you any help

Comment: Use Layout Managers to fix the   position and size of your JTextArea and  other hidden components , and so they will be visible. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, replacing `scrollPane.getViewport().add(panel)` by `scrollPane.getViewport().setView(panel)` will solve the issue.